# Yamaha I455 Indian Music Keyboard, Dual Voice - Drums and grand piano

Tags: keyboard

How can I use my [Yamaha i455 Indian music keyboard](http://in.yamaha.com/en/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalkeyboards/portable_keyboards/psr-i455/) to play drums and piano or sitar at the same time?

Comment: I know very little about traditional Indian music, but from watching the demonstration videos, this looks like a digital musical instrument with amazingly powerful auto-accompaniment features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the entire user's manual. You need to learn about these concepts: multitimbral operation, how to set a keyboard split point, and how to use the sequencer ("Recording") and auto-accompaniment features.

On the link you have provided in your question, at the Yamaha product information page, there are demonstration videos. Under the "Support" tab you can find instruction manuals which you can download.

I found another link to the PDF user's manual here.

http://www.manualslib.com/manual/474749/Yamaha-Psr-I455.html

There are sections in the manual with the following headings which you should read carefully:

- Playing a Split Voice in the Left-Hand Area
- Recording Your Performance: Track Structure of a Song
- Voice Settings: Selecting a Dual Voice and Selecting a Split Voice

Comment: Yes I see in the manual Everything is there... but the main point i liked is the support tab whcih you said i will definitely visit...